# Is there a way to link the animation of two layers?

Tags: video, after-effects

I am building a kinetic type-style video and am struggling to get some of the animations to sync correctly.
In this particular example I am trying to have a text box (imported .ai file) rotate with the text inside (made with an AE animation preset) but at the moment they fall out of alignment part way through the animation.
Is there a simple means of link their animations so they stay in the same position (relative to each other) or do I have to fiddle with the registration point to make sure their animations sync together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is layer [parenting](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/aftereffects/cs/using/WS3878526689cb91655866c1103906c6dea-7da0a.html).

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for **Anchor Point.**

Position on composition is the sum of Position+Anchor Point. Play a little with it to understand how it works. Simple press "A" on keyboard to show this propertie on timeline.

If you need to link values (position to anchor points or whatever) of each layer use the @ operator (on timeline too). This will give u an moving "arrow" to link both values. The icon of this tool really looks like a "@". After linked, propertie 'childed' will follow propertie "father" . Parenting is the name of this tool in AE.